# dynamically adding event handlers to dynamic panels in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic

Ok so i've been struggling to get my head around this for a few fays not and need some help.

so i have a series of panels that are generated

example:

```
For i as integer 1 to dt.rows.count
    dim subpan as new panel
    *Code for creating panel"
Next
```

the problem is i need to be able to add event handlers to each of them including, click, mouseEnter and mouseLeave but i can't figure out how to index each panel so that they can be accessed and identified. i tried using a property but that didn't seem to work or i was doing it wrong.

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) function:

```
For i as integer 1 to dt.rows.count 
    dim subpan as new panel 
    subpan.ID = "subpan1"  ' REQUIRED AND MUST BE UNIQUE
    AddHandler subpan.Click, AddressOf subpan1_Click  ' CLICK EVENT HANDLER ALSO UNIQUE
    ' ETC.
Next 

Private Sub subpan1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' CODE TO HANDLE CLICK EVENT
End Sub
```

I should mention that you can route all click events to the same event handler, they don't have to be unique unless each panel requires custom logic.

Comment: how do u do subpan.ID as ID isnt a property of a panel

Comment: My apologies, I did that off the top of my head. It might be the Name property.

Comment: yeh ive done that but its only assigning it to the first one in the series

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddHandler` to add the handler:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
    Dim subpan As New Panel()

    'Code for creating panel

    'Attach events:
    AddHandler subpan.Click, AddressOf Some_Listener
    'etc.
Next
```

You can then access the current `Panel` in the event handlers by casting the `sender` argument to `Panel`.